# How to Map through HTML collection and add dynamic elements to each?

Tags: javascript, simple-html-dom

I want to map through an HTML collection array.

```js
let mainElem = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('ant-upload-list-picture-card-container'))
```

and add another element to each item in array.

I tried to iterate through each of them. It was working fine but element emptydiv gets appended only at the last item

```js
Array.prototype.map.call(mainElem, (tag, i) => {
         emptyDiv.classList.add(`dynamicClass_${i}`)
                
                if (i === 0) {
                    emptyDiv.classList.add('dynamic_active_class');
                }
                else {
                    emptyDiv.classList.add('dynamic_inactive_class');
                }
                tag.appendChild(emptyDiv);
        })
```

Comment: What is `emptyDiv`?

Answer (score 0):

`emptyDiv` points to the same element in each iteration, meaning you are appending it at one index, in the next index, you take it from the previous, and append to the current index.

If you want to append an empty div to every index, you have to create a new element at each iteration:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(mainElem, (tag, i) => {

     const emptyDiv=document.createElement("div")

     emptyDiv.classList.add(`dynamicClass_${i}`)
            
            if (i === 0) {
                emptyDiv.classList.add('dynamic_active_class');
            }
            else {
                emptyDiv.classList.add('dynamic_inactive_class');
            }
            tag.appendChild(emptyDiv);
    })
```